# What is the proper word for ‘Music Production’?

Tags: single-word-requests

And also for music producer.

Muzika Produktado?
Notproducktado?

Produktando?
Produktandisto?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper word for ‘Music Production’? And also for music producer.

Vi povas uzi `muzikproduktado` kaj `mukzikproduktisto`.

Vidu la jenan alineon en la retejo de [Vinilkosmo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinilkosmo).

> Vinilkosmo estas sendependa eldonejo kiu produktas, eldonas, kaj distribuas ekskluzive esperanto-bandojn kaj artistojn en ĉiuj eblaj aktualaj muzikstiloj (roko, popo, folko, kanzono, tradicia, punko, hardkoro, mondmuziko, elektroniko, regeo, skao, hiphopo, ktp.). La artistoj venas el la tuta mondo. (https://www.vinilkosmo-mp3.com/eo/)

Ankaŭ en [tekstaro.com](https://tekstaro.com/) vi trovos tion, ĉu [kunmetite](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5fc9744bbd775) ĉu per [du vortoj](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5fc9746dfebc2):

> ...kiam la registaro reformis la sistemon de muzika produktado

aŭ

> ... Mustafa “Muĉe” Ĉengiĉ, sonteknikisto kaj muzikproduktisto